# C# how to sort a list without implementing IComparable manually?

Tags: c#

I have a fairly complex scenario and I need to ensure items I have in a list are sorted.

Firstly the items in the list are based on a struct that contains a sub struct.

For example:

```
public struct topLevelItem
{
 public custStruct subLevelItem;
}

public struct custStruct
{
  public string DeliveryTime;
}
```

Now I have a list comprised of topLevelItems for example:

```
var items = new List<topLevelItem>();
```

I need a way to sort on the DeliveryTime ASC. What also adds to the complexity is that the DeliveryTime field is a string. Since these structs are part of a reusable API, I can't modify that field to a DateTime, neither can I implement IComparable in the topLevelItem class.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*It sounds like you need to get canonicalized date sorting even though your date is represented as a string, yes?* Well, you can use LINQ's `OrderBy` operator, but you will have to parse the string into a date to achieve correct results:

```
items = items.OrderBy(item => DateTime.Parse(item.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime))
             .ToList();
```

**Update:**

I've added this in for completeness - a real example of how I use ParseExact with Invariant culture:

```
var returnMessagesSorted = returnMessages.OrderBy((item => DateTime.ParseExact(item.EnvelopeInfo.DeliveryTime, ISDSFunctions.GetSolutionDateTimeFormat(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
return returnMessagesSorted.ToList();
```

You can always implement a separate IComparer class, it's not fun, but it works well:

```
public class TopLevelItemComparer : IComparer<topLevelItem>
{
  public int Compare( topLevelItem x, topLevelItem y )
  {
      return DateTime.Parse(x.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime).CompareTo(
             DateTime.Parse(y.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime) );
  }
}

items.Sort( new TopLevelItemComparer() );
```

Be aware that most `Sort()` methods in the .NET framework accept an `IComparer` or `IComparer<T>` which allows you to redefine the comparison semantics for any type. Normally, you just use `Comparer<T>.Default` - or use an overload that essentially supplies this for you.

Comment: sounds good, I guess adding a format string (with parseExact) and invariant culture to the mix couldn't hurt?

Comment: @JL: The more specific you can make your code the better. Letting Parse() attempt to auto-detect your date format isn't a great idea when you can avoid it. The exception is when you are writing internationalized code and you want to use the thread's current culture settings.

Answer (score 7):

Create a new type that implements [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) and use an instance of it to compare the objects.

```
public class topLevelItemComparer : IComparer<topLevelItem>
{
    public int Compare(topLevelItem a, topLevelItem b)
    {
        // Compare and return here.
    }
}
```

You can then call Sort() like this:

```
var items = new List<topLevelItem>();
// Fill the List
items.Sort(new topLevelItemComparer());
```

Comment: It always seemed odd to me that IComparer is still the preferred way to do this. A `Func<T,T,int>` would be so much nicer.

Comment: @Matt Greer, I don't know about "preferred", but you can sort using a Comparison<T> delegate (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx).

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen, ah nice, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ:

```
items = items.OrderBy(item => item.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime).ToList();
```

Comment: I guess I need to do some string to datetime conversion too?

Comment: This is creating an entirely new list, not sorting the existing one in place.

Comment: Probably, but if your string is in a standard format you can just throw in a call to `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: I guess I could live with having a new list, solution seems good, except wondering about the datetime aspect.

Comment: This also doesn't take into account that the OP might be using an older version of .NET

Answer (score 4):

If you want to perform an in-place sort then you can use the [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) overload that takes a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) argument and pass an anonymous function/lambda:

```
items.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Parse(x.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime).CompareTo(
                     DateTime.Parse(y.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime)));
```

If you prefer to create a new sorted sequence rather than an in-place sort then LINQ's `OrderBy` is probably the way to go, as others have already mentioned.

Comment: +1 Didn't realize List had a sort overload that takes a delegate. Many other places in the framework only accept IComparer so a little surprised to see it here.

Comment: I didn't realize this either.  Exactly what I was looking for too

Answer (score 2):

Having had this problem before I once implemented a LambdaComparer that did the compare based on an arbitrary lambda expression.  Not exact code but something along these lines:

```
public class LambdaComparer : IComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T,T,int> _func;

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T,T,int> function)
    {
        _func = function;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return _func(x,y);
    }
}
```

Big advantage of this is you get a nice reusable chunk of code.

Answer (score 1):

To sort the `items` list itself:

```
Comparison<topLevelItem> itemComparison = (x, y) => {
    DateTime dx;
    DateTime dy;

    bool xParsed = DateTime.TryParse(x.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime, out dx);
    bool yParsed = DateTime.TryParse(y.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime, out dy);

    if (xParsed && yParsed)
        return dx.CompareTo(dy);
    else if (xParsed)
        return -1; // or 1, if you want invalid strings to come first
    else if (yParsed)
        return 1; // or -1, if you want invalid strings to come first
    else
        // simple string comparison
        return x.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime.CompareTo(y.subLevelItem.DeliveryTime);
};

items.Sort(itemComparison);
```

This approach has the advantage of:

1. Sorting the list in place (that is, if you actualy *want* the list sorted in-place)
2. Sorting by actual `DateTime` values, rather than strings, **BUT**...
3. Not throwing an exception if a string does not represent a valid `DateTime` (basically, all the invalid strings will end up on one side of the list)